# JSON iOS parsing string

Tags: ios, json, parsing

```
{"response":[33689822,64091979,69682048,74160161]}
```

-

```
- (void)requestCompleted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{   
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"okRequest|| %@",responseString);

    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

    // Prepare URL request to download statuses from Twitter

    // Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:responseString];

    // parse the JSON response into an object
    // Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects
    NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

    // Each element in statuses is a single status
    // represented as a NSDictionary
    for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
    {
        //all other func..
        NSLog(@"%@ ", status);///This func prints only "response"
    }
}
```

How I can get array of numbers in "response"? (33689822,64091979,69682048,74160161)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (NSNumber *number in [statuses objectForKey:@"response"]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either parse the JSON data yourself, or better, use a library like TouchJSON to do it for you.

Comment: @Nick Weaver, looks like you're right. +1 to you for having patience enough to resist pointing to the fine manual. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSONFragmentValue directly.

```
NSString *response=[request responseString];
id usableResp = [response JSONFragmentValue];
```